# Css creating a full width div on screen reduction

Tags: html, css

how to let the    divs    in the code below take 100% width when the screen size is reduced. on reducing the screen size, id="two" is floated to the next line leaving a gap on the right side of the page.

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>

<style>
#one, #two {
border: 1px solid;
min-width: 400px;
max-width: 100%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why don't you use media queries?

Comment: thanks, but I never tried it, thus I don't know how it works.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a media query to set the `div`s width to 100% till a specific break point.

```css
#one,
#two {
  border: 1px solid;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #one,
  #two {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Reference: [MDN - CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)